WSO2 IS x509 authenticator behind firewall
What options do we have to configure WSO2 IS x509Authenticator to work behind firewall  Where only 80 and 443 ports are allowed?
If we set x509 servlet this way
[custom_transport.x509.properties]
port="8443"
...
[authentication.authenticator.x509_certificate.parameters]
AuthenticationEndpoint="https://mydomain:8443/x509-certificate-servlet"

Then we'll not be able to access this endpoint behind the firewall.
So we set this location for nginx config.
location /x509-certificate-servlet {
    proxy_pass https://<is_server>:8443;

and x509
[authentication.authenticator.x509_certificate.parameters]
AuthenticationEndpoint="https://mydomain/x509-certificate-servlet"

x509 successfully authenticates user and redirects to https://mydomain:8443/commonauth. Which is obviously unreachable because of firewall blocking 8443 port.
I've seen similar topic WSO2 Identity Server X509 Authentication Behind Proxy but it doesn't elaborate about firewall problem.
The comment on the github issue https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/17484 tries to explain x509 authenticator workflow. From what I've read there I conclude that x509 servlet redirects to it's own commonauth endpoint not IS server's.
So we have two valid similar endpoints https://mydomain/commonauth and https://mydomain:8443/commonauth. For which I see no way to separate by nginx's locations on the same server port. Because the second one is not configurable.
One solution would be to register separate domain for the x509 servlet
[authentication.authenticator.x509_certificate.parameters]
AuthenticationEndpoint="https://mydomain-x509/x509-certificate-servlet"

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain-x509;
    ssl_verify_client optional_no_ca;
...
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8443;
        proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_escaped_cert;
...

but x509 servlet again redirects to https://mydomain:8443/commonauth
So this approach doesn't work either.
Is there working solution? What am I missing?

I recently published an article [1] detailing how to set up an X509 authenticator in a multi-node cluster configuration, fronted by NGINX. In my setup, I hosted the authenticator on the same port as the WSO2 Identity Server, which was port 9443. You might find this approach helpful in resolving your firewall issue. Could you give it a try and let me know if it works for your case?
[1] - https://medium.com/@dhaurapathirana/hosting-x509-certificate-authenticator-with-ssl-termination-in-a-wso2-is-multi-node-cluster-f4337971f6db

Did you try to setup by to your article? I may be wrong. But it doesn't work because:

The article omits some important settings that we need to do according to the official docs.  [custom_transport.x509.properties] for example.
we cannot bind two services on the same port.  Assuming that you're referring to this setting custom_transport.x509.properties.port="9443".  It conflicts with the server port 9443.
adding valve jar leads to NoClassDefFoundError.  Does the article refer to old versions of IS?


We can host the x509 authenticator in the same tomcat server as IS with the same port (9443). In that case, you don't need to configure [custom_transport.x509.properties]. If you configure these properties then it might lead to errors as it tries to host two servers in the same port. Moreover, when you included the jar, what is the exact NoClassDefFoundError? Hope you already verified whether jar is available in the plugins folder. If so no need to add it.

This clearly diverges from the docs.

The jar is in the right directory. I've built the latest 1.1.12 version. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/utils/CarbonUtils  at org.wso2.carbon.extension.identity.x509Certificate.valve.config.X509ServerConfiguration.getInstance(X509ServerConfiguration.java:49).....
And this exception have been raised by it.
I cannot paste full exception and this is not the right place.
